# Error: Could not execute statement on remote server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, parameters, output, exec

I am getting error using similar syntax. With `numeric` it works, but for `varchar` it doesn't:

This is OK:

```
DECLARE @DATA1 NUMERIC(3) 
SET @DATA1 = 0 

EXECUTE ('BEGIN PPC.PRUEBA (?); END;', @DATA1 OUTPUT) AT [GETESTING]
SELECT @DATA1
```

But this code:

```
DECLARE @DATA2 varchar(50) SET @DATA2 = '' EXECUTE ('BEGIN PPC.PRUEBA_CHAR (?); END;',@DATA2 OUTPUT) AT GETESTING SELECT @DATA2
```

throws this error:

> Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 9
>   Could not execute statement on remote server 'GETESTING'.

Comment: This is not an Oracle code. Tag proper RDBMS.

Comment: This is not an Oracle Tag, I think is is Sql Server?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, In fact, the Main code is Sql-Server but as you can see The content of the execute function is Oracle.

Comment: I am calling an Oracle function with an OUTPUT parameter from Sql-Server and need to receive the answer from Oracle Server.

Comment: The sintax is Sql-Server, but I am calling an Oracle function: PRUEBA_CHAR(?)  with only one output parameter:

Comment: This is the oracle function code: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PPC.PRUEBA_CHAR (    OUT_SALIDA1 OUT VARCHAR2    )
IS

begin

OUT_SALIDA1:= 'A';

EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
/

Answer (score 0):

After lot of tests with a pair of similar Windows Servers and also Windows 10 desktop I found that the source of the issue is the version of Oracle Drive. 
We are runnig Oracle 11 and till now we install 11 drivers for Sql-Plus or Toad. 
But with this new Windows Servers 2012 and newer Sql-Server 2016, SSMS 17.3 looks like the old Oracle client has issues like reported in this post.
After installing Oracle Driver, same we have in servers that ths Procedure call worked it begun to work were it previously doesn't. Even from Window 10 with SSMS.
Thank you